# Firebase-mlkit barcode scanner License

Tags: android, firebase, qr-code, barcode-scanner, firebase-mlkit

I want to use read barcode capabilities of the firebase library in a commercial project.
Additionally, no data could be store on the cloud (it should be done only on a client side)

Where could I find license information for this library? Is it Apache 2.0?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/read-barcodes

Edit:
Also is the "old" version of this library free?
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

License information can be found in `third_party_licenses.txt` and `third_party_licenses.json` in the aar file that you can download (and then unzip) from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-ml-vision/24.0.2

Both the Barcode scanning APIs in ML Kit and in Mobile Vision are offered free of charge.

Comment: Is firebase ML barcode reader still free of charge ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/read-barcodes